# Headphone icon won't go away

Tags: audio, notification-icons, headphones

A headphone icon popped up on my LG G3 phone yesterday.  It won't let me hear phone calls if I call or receive them.  It also won't let me play music.  The only way I can hear anything is if I plug the headphones in.

I've tried cleaning out the headphone jack, making sure the hearing aid impairment was off, and I even reset my phone.  Nothing has worked and I
still have the problem.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like hardware issue, try pluging in and out headphones maybe it will fix itself.

Comment: try rebooting the device

Answer (score 1):

I simply insert a needle inside the audio jack to short-circuit it. It works and the headset icon disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I think the headphone jack is shorted, and it needs to be cleaned or replaced by a new one. Unfortunately, both need to disassemble the phone. Here is a short [YouTube video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=IUR4wVtqX7M) for how to replace the jack.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me as well. Took a Q-Tip with rubbing alcohol and cleaned it out but didn't work. Took an air duster and blew it up there and it's now gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem on Redmi Note 4 (I have it too right now :D). Headphone jack is damaged and thinks there is a headphone plugged in permanently which results in android never playing sound over the speakers. For phone calls you can turn on the big speaker so atleast you still can hear callers.
The only way to fix the issue is to completely remove the jack (and replace it).